# I cannot change form input data using Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

> vuex do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

I tried to look for something here, because the error is very common, but I couldn't solve it yet

I'm trying to create a stateful form with vuex

Component

```
<el-form ref="form" :model="form" label-width="130px">


   <el-form-item label="Entrada">
       <el-input v-model="form.dataEntrada"></el-input>
   </el-form-item>


</el-form>
```

Computed

```
computed: {
        form: {
            get () {
                return this.$store.state.form
            },
            set (value) {
                this.$store.commit('setForm', value)
            }
        }
    }
```

Store

```
state: {
    form: {
      dataEntrada: ''   
    },
    
},

mutations: {
    setForm(state, payload){
        state.form = payload
    }
}

actions: {},

getters: {},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to map `v-model` to a piece of Vuex `state`. Instead use `@input` or `@change` in the input to commit the changes to the store and use `:value` to bind the value from the store.

```
<el-input :value="form.dataEntrada" @input="updateValue" />
```

and in the script

```
computed: { form: function() {  return this.$store.state.form }},

methods: { updateValue: function(e) { this.$store.commit('setValue', e.target.value) }}
```

## Update

*Template*

```
<template>
<div class="hello">
<el-form ref="form" :model="form" label-width="130px">
  <el-row>
    <el-col :span="4">
      <el-form-item label="Entrada">
        <el-input v-model="form.dataEntrada"></el-input>
      </el-form-item>
    </el-col>

    <el-col :span="4">
      <el-form-item label="Fornecedor">
        <el-input v-model="form.fornecedor"></el-input>
      </el-form-item>
    </el-col>

    <el-col :span="4">
      <el-form-item label="Codigo">
        <el-input v-model="form.nfe.codigo"></el-input>
      </el-form-item>
    </el-col>

    <el-col :span="4">
      <el-form-item label="Numero">
        <el-input v-model="form.nfe.numero"></el-input>
      </el-form-item>
    </el-col>
  </el-row>
  <el-form-item>
    <el-button type="primary" @click="onSubmit">Criar</el-button>
  </el-form-item>
</el-form>
</div>
</template>
```

*Vue*

```
data() {
   return {
     form: this.$store.state.form
   }
},
methods: {
  onSubmit() {
    this.$store.commit("setForm", this.form);
  }
}
```

*store*

In case if you are not setting the form elements to required and want to update only the changed fields, below is the code.

```
mutations: {
setForm(state, payload) {
  state.form = {
    ...state.form,
    ...payload
  };
}
},
```

Comment: thank you. Error: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: Here - e.target.value

Comment: `console.log(e)` to see whats in `e`. It has to be the event object

Comment: console.log(e) - The input value is shown. However it does not store the data in the form.dataEntrada

Comment: You have change your mutation accordingly like `setValue(state, payload){ state.form.dataEntrada = payload }`

Comment: Will I need more inputs, is it not possible to do this using a chained form?  form:{dataEntrada:'', name:"" } etc..

Comment: Could you please reproduce your issue in codesandbox? so that it can be understood correctly

Comment: Ok I will do it now. 1 minute

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-feistel-26r4v?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handler

Comment: @marcelo.delta i tried the above code in your codesandbox and it is working fine. Please  apply the changes carefully and check